# Allow access for MQTT on Ubuntu Server running on Azure

Tags: mqtt, esp8266

I have a Ubuntu Server 14.04 running on an Azure machine. I have installed MQTT broker on this Ubuntu Server. Moreover, I have multiple ESP8266 devices that are assumed to subscribe and publish to different MQTT topics via this broker. Now my problem is that when I connect two devices to Broker, one for receiving data and other for publishing, they work fine but as I try to connect one more device to broker all devices stop working and my ESPs just display this message "trying to connect Broker" over and over again.
(In endpoints of my machine I've added 1883 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS and 22 for SSH)

**My question is how I can allow multiple devices to communicate with MQTT broker running on Azure broker?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQTT clients get clientID as parameter before connection to provide uniqueness. ESP8266's has unique ChipID. So use it to hit the issue. 
Here the example for Arduino firmware :

```
WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(wifiClient);
mqttClient.setServer(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_BROKER_PORT);

String clientId = "IoTDevice-" + String(ESP.getChipId());
mqttClient.connect(clientId.c_str(), MQTT_USERNAME, MQTT_KEY);
```

Here is NodeMCU firmware example :

```
mqtt_cli:connect(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_BROKER_PORT, 0, CALLBACK_FN);

mqtt_cli = mqtt.Client("IoTDevice-"..node.chipid(), 120, MQTT_USERNAME, MQTT_KEY);
```

Comment: I was sending a constant value in place of clientID and that was the cause of the problem. Now I have a small question that is, are clientID and username related to each other in any way?  Usernames and passwords are registered in MQTT broker database and one cannot use a username which is not in broker database but what about clientId ? is it necessary to register a clientId in broker before using it?

Comment: And can I have one username and password for all of my ESP8266 devices but with different clientIDs? will it work?

Comment: Client id is using for handling of  communication and qos at broker side. It is not related with authenticity and user names. User name and password is using to authenticate communication to correct topics. Client id is nothing to register but username is. Second question, yes, you can use same username and password for your all esp communication in your project. Watch out the topics that you send data and subscribe for a healty communication.

Answer (score 2):

All client devices needs to have unique client ids. The situation you have described sounds exactly like what happens if all your esp8266 devices have the same hardcoded client id

Comment: So how can I have unique client IDs? In my case, I am using a unique topic for each device.eg, home/room1/device1, home/room1/device2. Isn't supposed to work?

Comment: Client ids are totally separate from topics, you pass them in with the connection details

Comment: @NaumanShakir pass the ESP's unique device identifier to the MQTT client like doing in answer below. As hardillb denotes, they need to have unique client ids, possibly you are passing a constant.